# A small modification needed in html script using javascript, i m not able to sort out

Tags: javascript

tis my code

```
<div class="rButtons">
<input type="radio" name="numbers" value="10" onclick="uncheck();" />10
<input type="radio" name="numbers" value="20"  onclick="uncheck();" />20
<input type="radio" name="numbers" value="other" onclick="check(this);"/>other
<input type="text" id="other_field" name="other_field" onblur="checktext(this);"/>
</div>
```

this is css code

```
<style type="text/css">
#other_field
{
visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
```

this is js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function uncheck()
 {
   document.getElementById('other_field').style.visibility = "hidden";
 }
function check(inputField)
{
    if(inputField.checked)
    {
        document.getElementById('other_field').style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
function checktext(inputField)
{
    if(isNaN(inputField.value))
    {
        alert('only numbers are allowed..');
        return false;
    }
    else if( (inputField.value % 10 ) != 0)
    {
        alert('only multiples of 10..');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
</script>
```

All is well..
but the problem is this.. when i click "other" radio button it opens up a new blank field, but when i click back to 10 or 20 it stays there.. How can i make this disappear??

I know answer is easy.. But i tried many things but not working..

Thanks

Comment: This already works for me on Chrome and Firefox. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDxqj/). Are you seeing this issue in a certain browser? You may have additional code on your page that could be causing an issue, so you might post a Fiddle that shows your problem.

Comment: @Marc Baumbach This works for me also.. just a major glitch.. thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with JQuery its more simples like this

```
<script>
 var $radios = $('input:radio[name=numbers]');
        if ($radios.is(':checked') === true) {
           $("#other_field").show();
        }     
        else
        {
           $("#other_field").hide();
        }   

</script>
```

Comment: I have jquery-1.4.2.js.. will ur code work on this??

Comment: yes, just put that in a function and invoke it in "onchange" of radiobutton, or put it on document ready try it ;)

Comment: I tried what u said..
<script>
function blahblahblah()
{
 var $radios = $('input:radio[name=numbers]');
    if ($radios.is(':checked') === true) {
       $("#other_field").show();
    }     
    else
    {
       $("#other_field").hide();
    }   
}
</script>

and i called like this
<input type="radio" name="numbers" value="other" onchange="blahblahblah();"/>other

but not worked..

Comment: i will give you the source 1 min

Answer (score 0):

full code for you:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowTextBox()
    {
        if ($("input[name=radiobutton1]:checked").val() == "show")      
        {       
           $("#text_box_to_show").show();
        }     
        else
        {
           $("#text_box_to_show").hide();
        }   
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Example</h3>
  <input name="radiobutton1" type="radio" value="show" onChange="ShowTextBox();">Show
  <input name="radiobutton1" type="radio" value="hide" checked onChange="ShowTextBox();">Hide
  <input type="text" id="text_box_to_show" name="textfield" style="display:none;">
</body>
</html>
```