# When I click "other" radio button nothing happens. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A small modification needed in html script using javascript, i m not able to sort out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482174/a-small-modification-needed-in-html-script-using-javascript-i-m-not-able-to-sor)

HTML:

```
<div class="rButtons">
<input type="radio" name="numbers" value="10" onclick="uncheck();" />10
<input type="radio" name="numbers" value="20"  onclick="uncheck();" />20
<input type="radio" name="numbers" value="other" onchange="blahblahblah();"/>other
<input type="text" id="other_field" name="other_field" onblur="checktext(this);"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#other_field{
visibility: hidden;
width:40px;
height:14px;
border:1px solid #777;
background-color:#111;
font-size:10px;
color:#666;
}
</style>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
function blahblahblah()
{
 var $radios = $('input:radio[name=numbers]');
    if ($radios.is(':checked') === true) {
       $("#other_field").show();
    }     
    else
    {
       $("#other_field").hide();
    }   
}
</script>
```

All is well.. but the problem is this.. when I click "other" radio button nothing happens.. while it should be opening other field.

Comment: Do not use inline events! You are using jQuery, utilize it to add events!

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($('input[name=numbers]:checked').val() === 'other') {
    // show hidden field
}
```

This will find whichever radio button is `checked`, and check its value is "other".

Answer (score 1):

If `blahblahblah` is only ever being called by the `other` radio button, you don't need to worry about most of the logic you have written. Try binding the handler via jQuery specifically to the `other` radio button.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="otherRadio" name="numbers" value="other"/>other
```

JS:

```
$('#otherRadio').on('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#other_field").show();
    } else {
        $("#other_field").hide();
    }
});
```

If you're unable to add the ID to the markup for some reason, you can use a different selector in it's place such as `$('input[type="radio"]:contains("other")');`

Comment: The JS code you mentioned, 
1. I have to put in <script> </script> in order to implement?
2. I CAN PUT THIS CODE ONLY IN HEAD OR ANYWHERE THROUGHOUT HTML??

Comment: @user1999428 you generally want to put javascript in a javascript file, and include it in the HTML via a `<script>` tag in the header.

Comment: I did what u mentioned, now it is showing a static new textfield to the right of "other" radio button with value as "other" ;(

Comment: @user1999428 it's supposed to. that's what you had in your markup you posted in the question.